# My aws ec instance is not able to connect to my redis cluster

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, amazon-elasticache

My aws ec instance is not able to connect to my redis cluster,
the ping is also timedout as well.
both my aws ec instance and redis cluster are in the same VPC and same sub network id.
redis cluster has the security group which allows all the inbound traffic
and the ec instance has the security group which allows all the outbound traffic
please help me check if I missed anything,
thanks very much.

Comment: I wouldn't read too much into ping not working. Not all systems respond to ping (Redis may, I'm not sure). Presumably you have worked through the instructions at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/accessing-elasticache.html.

Comment: @ValorZ, can you please share the subnet configuration as well, are you using private subnet or public subnet?